# Multiple MD1200s, Multiple External Connections Increase Throughput?

Tags: sas, direct-attached-storage

I am looking at a setup with two Dell MD1200s loaded with 6Gbs SATA drives.
What I am trying to figure out is if a single card with two external inputs would be a bottleneck, or if it would be better to have two cards and connect one MD1200 to each one.

Comment: Is throughput the main consideration for your storage solution?

Answer (score 2):

That very much depends on the SAS HBA in question - if it can handle both ports at full speed (most should) and there's no PCIe bottleneck either, there's no advantage in using two cards.

For example, an LSI 9211 8e HBA has got a PCIe 2.0 x8 slot interface, supporting a maximum net host transfer rate of appr. 4 GB/s. Each mini-SAS 6G connector (four lanes) supports up to 2.4 GB/s, so any slot with less than x8 may significantly limit total throughput - which might not be all too relevant for HDD arrays or for small workloads.

Comment: Would be something like the PERC H200 flashed.  I think when flashed it uses the LSI 9211 8e image.

Comment: @Dizzy49 I have update the answer with a suitable example.